# How to get mount point from a given path

Tags: go, system-calls

As title mentioned, I want to get mount point from a given path. For example, execute the command `df /etc`, the result is:

```
(my system is MacOS Catalina 10.15.1, go version go1.13.3 darwin/amd64)
➜  / df /etc
Filesystem   512-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1  976490576 628632776 308713384    68% 2457719 4879995161    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
```

then "/System/Volumes/Data" is what I need.
So how can I get the mount point from a given path in Go? (I tried `syscall.Stat_t{}`, but failed)

Comment: df on Linux parses [/proc/self/mountinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). There's also /proc/self/mounts which has the same format as /etc/fstab. I don't know if these exist on MacOS as well or if there are differences in the format.

Comment: @Peter it is a solution, but I still wonder whether there is syscall in Go. (Maybe, using exec module to execute shell command `df` is also helpful)

Comment: Neither `/proc` nor exec `df` is at all portable. The best bet would be to use [`syscall.Statfs`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Statfs) or [`golang.org/x/sys/unix.Statfs`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Statfs); unfortunately those aren't entirely portable either and any imports of those packages should be in a file with appropriate build constraints. On the plus side, my experience of setting the build constraints very inclusive and just checking that it cross-compiles with various `GOOS`,`GOARCH` combinations (see `go tool dist list`) has always worked.